# If $f,g \in L^2([-\pi,\pi])$ and are periodic with period $2\pi$ then the convolution is integrable

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, lebesgue-integral

If $f,g \in L^2([-\pi,\pi])$ and are periodic with period $2\pi$ then the convolution is integrable. Can somebody comment whether my proof is correct?

$\int_{[-\pi,\pi]} |\int_{[-\pi,\pi]} f(y)g(x-y)dy|dx \leq \int_{[-\pi,\pi]} (\int_{[-\pi,\pi]} |f(y)||g(x-y)|dy)dx$ by triangle inequality. Now we focus on the inner integral (can iterate by tonnelli since non negative).
$\int_{[-\pi,\pi]} |f(y)||g(x-y)|dy \leq \|f\|_{L^2{[-\pi,\pi]}} \sqrt{\int_{[-\pi,\pi]}|g(x-y)|^2 dy}.$ Now make a substitution $u= x-y$, then $du=-dy$ to get that the integral on the right equals $\sqrt{\int_{[x-\pi,x+\pi]}|g(u)|^2 du}$
But g periodic of period $2\pi$ so this simply equals $\sqrt{\int_{[-\pi,\pi]}|g(u)|^2 du}= \|g\|_{L^2([-\pi,\pi])}.$ So all together we get the double integral is less or equal to $2\pi \|f\|_{L^2([-\pi,\pi])} \|g\|_{L^2([-\pi,\pi])} <\infty$

Is this correct? I am hesitant as I know it is really trivial that the periodicity means the two integrals are equal but I haven't been able to show it mathematically. Otherwise is everything correct? Thanks.

Comment: You did show it mathematically... You are not sure about the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, or what you call the Tonnelli theorem (that if everything converges absolutely, then we don't care of the order of summation and integration), or what ?

Comment: Thanks, I mean I don't know that the integral from $x-\pi$ to $x+\pi$ is the same as the one from $-\pi$ to $\pi.$

Comment: It is obvious by $2\pi$-periodicity. If $h$ is $2\pi$-periodic then $\int_{a}^{a+2\pi}h(x)dx = \int_{a}^{2\pi}+\int_{2\pi}^{a+2\pi}h(x)dx=\int_{a}^{2\pi}+\int_{0}^{a}h(x)dx= \int_0^{2\pi} h(x)dx$

Comment: Thanks! Otherwise the proof is correct?